# use sass function inside react component inline style

Tags: reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I have a sass function that I want to import and use in a react component. The function accepts an argument that comes from a react state:

```
@function calculate-green($count) {
  $red: nth($green, 1);
  $green: nth($green, 2);
  $blue: nth($green, 3);
  @return rgb($red, $green, calc($blue - $count));
}
```

React:

```
style={{backgroundColor: calculateGreen(count)}}
```

The way I want to use it requires the react state which will update and the inline style color will update automatically.

Originally I was calculating the rgb value in the react component but I want to use sass variables for color. If I can do it using the sass function I won't have to manually change all the react components calculating the color and can just change the one variable of $green.

I haven't found anything similar to this online exactly. And the ideas I did find all were using webpack and I'm using vite.

Comment: `sass` is a preprocessor. In other words, it's a smarter way to write CSS, but it gets compiled into CSS when the app is compiled. At runtime, all your sass code has been parsed into regular CSS. That's what the browser gets and understands. These days CSS is getting smarter and some sass features have been ported to it but, afaik, there's no support for runtime sass functions. You can get this done in JS, though. There are several packages featuring color utilities. Also note this type of functionality can often be achieved using CSS variables.